# Посчитать место занимаемое в таблице

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, администрирование, percona

Категорически приветствую!
Существует mysql-сервер (`mysqld  Ver 5.6.36-82.0 for Linux on x86_64 (Percona Server (GPL), Release 82.0, Revision 58e846a)`) с innodb БД общим размером на диске ~ 90GB где на каждую таблицу приходится отдельный `ibd`.

```
26G /srv/mysql/data/db/table1.ibd
48G /srv/mysql/data/db/table2.ibd

CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `itemid` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `clock` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `value` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ns` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  KEY `table1_1` (`itemid`,`clock`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `table2` (
  `itemid` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `clock` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `value` double(16,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `ns` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  KEY `table2_1` (`itemid`,`clock`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Собсно вопрос в том, как без любой модификации БД (например, создание промежуточных таблиц) и желательно без операций записи на диск (например, `SELECT INTO OUTFILE`) посчитать фактически занимаемое место записей (в мегобайтах), где `itemid = 1111` ? Возможно ли это вообще? Никак не могу нагуглить.

P.S. Кол-во записей пока не могу сказать, `count` долго считает, их там овердофига :)

Comment: считаете к-во записей, умножаете на занимаемое место каждым типом данных - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/storage-requirements.html

Comment: Идея не плохая, но чёт не получается. В table1 которая 26G у меня 254289126 строк. Сумма всех полей = 24 байта. То есть, умножаем 254289126 на 24 затем делим на 1024 и ещё раз на 1024 и получаем 5820 MB , чёт не сходится. Что я делаю не так? :)

Comment: Выполните `show table status` он сообщает массу полезной информации. примерное количество записей в таблице, среднюю длину записи. Длину самих записей с требуемым itemid можно узнать умножив их количество на среднюю длину записи. НО физически занимаемое место имеет только примерное отношение к длине записи. Во первых таблица лежит страницами. страницы выстроены в дерево в порядке первичного ключа. В каждой странице кучу места занимает дополнительная информация для индекса, плюс еще свободное место

Comment: так же попробуйте сначала перестроить файл с таблицей - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimize-table.html

Comment: Так же надо понимать, что при частых добавлениях/удалениях многие страницы могут оказаться почти пустыми. например в странице лежало много записей с очень походим первичным ключем, со временем удалили почти все записи с этим ключем, но парочка осталась. Высока вероятность, что в эту страницу другие записи не пойдут так как у них не подходящие ключи и в итоге 4кб страница будет лежать ради одной записи

Comment: Оптимизировать таблицу на, почти, 50G? Ну чёт такое себе :) У меня по-моему нет места на временный файл который будет создан в процессе, и я боюсь поймать deadlock'и, что случилось со мной в эти выходные при оптимизации таблицы на 20G :(

Comment: И да, вы не сможете точно узнать сколько занимают _сейчас_ записи с itemid=1111 даже если перельете их целиком в другую таблицу, потому что в новой таблице они возможно лягут на диск гораздо компактнее.

Comment: Судя по структуре записи у вас копятся какие то данные по определенным itemid. И они по одним и тем же itemid постоянно дописываются с новым clock. Теперь вспомним то что я сказал выше "страницы таблицы физически организованы в дерево на основе первичного ключа". Вы записали скажем 10 записей с itemid  с 1 по 10 и одинаковым clock. Они легли в один блок, подряд, потому что других записей пока еще не было. Теперь вы добавляете за следующий срез времени еще 10 записей. MySQL обязан записать их между теми записями, что уже есть. в итоге он заводит новые страницы и начинает перераспределять записи

Comment: И тут возникает вопрос, как вы _обычно_ ищите информацию. по одному itemid или все (или многие item) за одну дату или интервал дат ? Если первое - то вам никуда не уйти от текущей структуры. А вот если второе - то вам надо что бы первичный ключ был наоборот (clock, itemid), тогда поиск по интервалу всех записей будет гораздо быстрее и главное - таблица при записи будет равномерно дописываться, MySQL не надо будет постоянно реорганизовывать страницы

Comment: Еще замечу, что мне недавно приходилось реорганизовывать таблицу на 120 Гб со сменой первичного ключа (там он вообще был случайным 16-байтным значением что приводило просто к катастрофически низкой производительности). Причем без остановки сервиса на несколько часов. Были созданы траггера, которые писали отдельно какие записи изменялись. После этого внешним скриптом записи были выгружены в текстовые зипованные файлы, отсортированы в порядке нового ключа и загружены в копию таблицы, после этого были долиты изменившиеся записи и таблицы переименованы

Comment: @Mike, спасибо огромное за подробные комментарии, но Вы сложно объясняете :) Я ничего не хочу реорганизовывать :) Это таблицы zabbix и мне нужно выяснить сколько примерно занимают несколько элементов данных, чтоб обосновать перед руководством их удаление :) Всё очень просто :)

Comment: Кстати, после их удаления таблицы не изменят свой размер. но освобожденное место внутри файла начнет использоваться другими записями по необходимости. И вашем случае я бы наверно просто поделил общий размер файла на количество записей в нем, получив среднее пространство необходимое на все нужды по хранению 1 записи. И умножил на кол-во предполагаемых к удалению.

Comment: Спасибо @Mike за Ваше время и знания, я наверно не мудрствуя лукаво, поступлю как Вы и предлагаете :) P.S. Да, я понимаю что место на диске не очистится, но я и не преследую такой цели; цель - очистить БД от хлама.